# Foreign key not rendering in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm building a commenting system, which is working fine but i'm now trying to integrate voting. So I made another model to handle that and I tried to pair it using `ForeignKey`. Not too familiar with `ForeignKey` but i've looked at some other answers here to see how to render it in the template. I tried that using the nested for loop in my template below but `{{ j.user }}` doesn't render anything. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField(default='1', max_length=12, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    comment_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_text

class CommentScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
    ...

    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
    score = CommentScore.objects.all()

    context = {
        'score': score,
        'comment_list': comment_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% for i in comment_list %}
    <div class='comment_div'>
        <h3>{{ i.author }}</h3>
        {% for j in comment_list.score_set.all %}
            {{ j.user }} #nothing comes up
        {% endfor %}
        <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

when using `_set`, the reverse relationship lookup, you must provide the full model name, you must also specify which instance this list of related models this "set" is for so it should be

```
{% for j in i.commentscore_set.all %}
{% empty %}
     No scores found
{% endfor %}
```

You may also wish to set a `related_name` for the foreign key

```
comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='scores')
...
{% for j in i.scores.all %}
```

Comment: `{% for j in i.commentscore_set.all %}` still isn't working

Comment: @Zorgan - Are you sure you have scores for the given comments? You can check this by setting `score` in your view to `CommentScore.objects.filter(comment__destination=id)`

Comment: What do you mean? They don't have scores yet as i've only just created the model, but it should default to 0 if there is no score. And the field in my original question, `user`, isnt showing up either.

Comment: @Zorgan - I don't understand, if there isn't anything to iterate over then of course theres nothing it will be able to show, I presume you're looking for `{% empty %}` also.

Comment: The `default=0` so `0` should show up instead of nothing. And `user` isn't showing up which is unrelated to scoring so there must be another problem.

Comment: @Zorgan - Try adding the `{% empty %}` as per my edit and hopefully that will make it clearer..

Comment: Ok so I tried that and it rendered `No Scores Found`. What does this mean?

Comment: @Zorgan - The default you speak of is the default value for a *field* on an *instance* of a `CommentScore`, you have no instances, therefore there is nothing to loop over.

Comment: It's getting abit clearer now, so can you just suggest how I can create an instance of CommentScore to see if it works?